# Excel: Column A values -> Input into series of functions -> Output to Column L

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to take a set of values in column A, each row would act as an input a series of functions I have in middle section that are not nestable, and finally taking the output of those functions into the respective row in Column L.

Here's a screenshot. Orange cell would be input from each row in Column A. Green cell is output from all the functions above it. First row in Column L is set to be equal to the green cell's output.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Since the input in Column A could vary (bonuses, etc), I can't just copy the same value from calculating one cell.

My goal is to have Column L automatically populated row by row.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to calculate? Seems there may be a simpler way of solving your real problem, once you explain it clearly.

Comment: Hi Ron - trying to calculate the federal tax applicable to each paycheck. The process is outlined in the PDF here on page 5. I've duplicated those steps onto the Excel sheet in the middle.
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15t.pdf
If there's an easier way, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: To clarify, the end result you are looking for is to have L2:L25 contain the results of running A2:A25 through the functions contained within D2:D11? If that is correct you would probably either use a user defined function (UDF) in each cell from L2:L25 or write a quick macro to loop through the A2:A25 and output the results to L2:L25. I can help with either one if you can clarify the requirement, including what the functions are between D2 and D11.

Comment: Thank you Justin. You described it exactly right. I ended up however developing a nested VLOOKUP formula (see below) and it got me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps in automating the calculation of Federal Tax Withholding.

And you can reduce the steps involved in going from the adjusted annual wage to the Fed Tax Withholding to a single formula.

Getting from Gross wage to Adjusted is dependent on entries made by the employee on his W4 (as is deciding which tax table to use).

Here is one method.

- Annualize the periodic payment *(eg gross salary * 24 in your example)*
- Subtract an amount depending on W4 entries (eg number of dependents) as calculated by the **employee** on line 3 of the W4
- Reduce further by entries employee may have made on line 4 of the W4
- Decide which withholding table to use based on employee checkmarks on the W4 (and there are six possibilities if using the latest version of W4)
- compute the tax.

The first three steps are simple subtractions
The fourth step depends on boxes checked by the employee.

The fifth step is a formula making extensive use of VLOOKUP.

For the Married Filing Jointly (MFJ) table (which is what I see in your example), for use in Excel you should simplify the table by retaining columns 1,3 and 4. And I `NAME`'d the table `MFJ`

[image]

The formula for annual FED WH tax, with the Adjusted Annual Wage in, let us say, A2, is:

```
A2: =VLOOKUP(A2,MFJ,2)+(A2-VLOOKUP(A2,MFJ,1))*VLOOKUP(A2,MFJ,3)
```

For the WH per paycheck, merely divide that by the number of pay periods per year (eg 24)

[image]

I hope this different approach will help you simplify your worksheet.

If this is for your personal paycheck, then your W4 is known and stable, and you can just enter a column of adjusted wages in some column, and compute your WH using the formula.

However, if your income will vary from period to period, there are alternative methods of computing withholding that you can look into, and are perfectly legal.

If this is for a number of employees, you'll have to also input the W4 data for each employee in order to make the adjusted annual wage computation, before you can figure the withholding.

*By the way, you really only need the `BaseIncome` and `Percent` columns from the tax tables.  You can compute the `BaseWH` column based on those numbers.*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to answer Ron. I ended up doing a bit more research and developed a solution.

To answer your questions, yes it's for personal paychecks and yes the income will vary period to period (due to bonuses and such). My goal is to forecast the federal income taxes that are being withheld. I'm following IRS 15-T's method just to make sure I'm pretty close to accurate.

Here's the formula I came up with. Yes it's long but it gets the job done:

```
=(((((A2*$E$1)-($E$2*4300))-VLOOKUP(((A2*$E$1)-($E$2*4300)),$D$4:$H$11,1,TRUE))*VLOOKUP(((A2*$E$1)-($E$2*4300)),$D$4:$H$11,4,TRUE))+VLOOKUP(((A2*$E$1)-($E$2*4300)),$D$4:$H$11,3,TRUE))/$E$1
```

I pasted it in B2 and dragged down and got the numbers I was looking for. May not be elegant but it works.

[Final Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7yxk.png)

Comment: It will only be accurate if your boss is using the same method.  But it should be reasonably close.